# Why does stunnel keep throwing "Address already in use (48)"?

Tags: django, https, stunnel

I am working on implementing Auth0 in a Django project, using stunnel to create the https connection. I followed [this instruction](https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/7012524#file-django-runserver-ssl-md)

This is my dev_https file:

```
pid=

cert = stunnel/stunnel.pem
foreground = yes
output = stunnel.log

[https]
accept=8080
connect=8000
TIMEOUTclose=1
```

However, when I want to start the server, using this command:

```
stunnel stunnel/dev_https &
python3 manage.py runserver&
```

I get the following:

```
[.] Configuration successful
[ ] Deallocating deployed section defaults
[ ] Binding service [https]
[ ] Listening file descriptor created (FD=9)
[ ] Setting accept socket options (FD=9)
[ ] Option SO_REUSEADDR set on accept socket
[.] Binding service [https] to :::8080: Address already in use (48)
[ ] Listening file descriptor created (FD=9)
[ ] Setting accept socket options (FD=9)
[ ] Option SO_REUSEADDR set on accept socket
[.] Binding service [https] to 0.0.0.0:8080: Address already in use (48)
[!] Binding service [https] failed
```

I tried changing the accept port from 8443 to 8080. Same result

I then checked for active processes on the port with

`lsof -i 8080`

This reveals that stunnel is already running on the port. I killed that process and tried again, but I get the same error.

**Specific questions**

1. Can someone briefly explain the reqeuest flow between the accept and connect ports, and how this relates to the normal port that I run Django on (port 8000)?
2. How do I fix this?

Thank you!
/Thomas